# rowsum based on groupings or conditions in r

Tags: r, grouping, conditional-statements, rowsum

I want to do [rowsum](/questions/tagged/rowsum) in [r](/questions/tagged/r) based on column names.

I have more than 50 columns and have looked at various solutions, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777678/r-data-frame-rowsums-of-selected-columns-by-grouping-vector).

However, this doesn't really answer my question. I have column names such as: 
`total_2012Q1, total_2012Q2, total_2012Q3, total_2012Q4` ,..., up to `total_2014Q4`, and other character variables. I want to add rows by year, so in the end, I would have three year columns: `total_2012, total_2013, total_2014`.

I don't want to [rowsum](/questions/tagged/rowsum) and select something like ..`sample[,2:5]`. Is there a way I can sum them without manually going through column numbers? Also, [split.default](/questions/tagged/split.default) is an option but if there are character variables as well, how do you deal only the int variables you want to sum up?

simple reproducible example (pre):

```
id total_2012Q1 total_2012Q2 total_2013Q1 total_2013Q2 char1 char2
 1         1231         5455         1534         2436    N     Y
 2         3948         1239          223          994    Y     N
```

reproducible example (post):

```
id total_2012 total_2013 char1 char2
 1       6686      3970     N     Y
 2       5187      1217     Y     N
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It's easier for folks to help with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That includes the code you've tried that you need help debugging, a representative sample of data, and the output you're trying to get

Comment: Thanks @camille. I've edited to include a simple example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `split.default`, i.e.

```
sapply(split.default(df, sub('^.*_([0-9]+)Q[0-9]', '\\1', names(df))), rowSums)
#     2012 2013
#[1,]    3   23
#[2,]    7   37
#[3,]    9   49
```

**DATA:**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(total_2012Q1 = c(1, 2, 3), total_2012Q2 = c(2, 
5, 6), total_2013Q1 = c(12, 15, 16), total_2013Q2 = c(11, 22, 
33)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this with `tidyverse` functions is to reshape the data into a long format so you have a column of `total_2012Q1`, `total_2012Q2`, etc. You can then separate that into years and quarters, where quarters are marked as being the last two characters in each string:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, starts_with("total")) %>%
  separate(key, into = c("year", "quarter"), sep = -2)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 6
#>      id char1 char2 year       quarter value
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1     1 N     Y     total_2012 Q1       1231
#> 2     2 Y     N     total_2012 Q1       3948
#> 3     1 N     Y     total_2012 Q2       5455
#> 4     2 Y     N     total_2012 Q2       1239
#> 5     1 N     Y     total_2013 Q1       1534
#> 6     2 Y     N     total_2013 Q1        223
#> 7     1 N     Y     total_2013 Q2       2436
#> 8     2 Y     N     total_2013 Q2        994
```

After that, you can group by your identifiers and year, sum up the values, and reshape it back to a wide format.

```r
df %>%
  gather(key, value, starts_with("total")) %>%
  separate(key, into = c("year", "quarter"), sep = -2) %>%
  group_by_at(vars(id:year)) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  spread(key = year, value = value)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#> # Groups:   id, char1, char2 [2]
#>      id char1 char2 total_2012 total_2013
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     1 N     Y           6686       3970
#> 2     2 Y     N           5187       1217
```

An approach like this, particularly gathering with `starts_with("total")` rather than hard-coded column names or column positions, lets you scale to larger datasets with many more columns.